# WiX: Multiple MSI files?

Tags: visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

Is it possible to have one "WiX Installer" project in a solution in Visual Studio, but that one project outputs multiple installer files (either by having multiple .wxs files or multiple `<Feature>`s or however else)? Perhaps one .wxs file for one .msi file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. 1 .wixproj == 1 .msi, with the exception that you can have multiple localized versions of that one .msi.

Answer (score 1):

We can create different Msi by passing different architecture to the same project. 32 bit msi and 64bit msi.

Same wxs file is used in both cases.