# 2 .msi files from one WiX Votive project

Tags: wix, windows-installer, votive

As the title says, I want to output 2 .msi files from one project (one is per-user, and the other is per-machine). I have seen in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5781994/wix-multiple-msi-files) thread that it can't be done in some conventional way, but perhaps there is a way to do so as some kind of hack in post-build.

I only need to rerun compilation and linking after the original build with slightly changed command line (actually, I need only different `Product.wxs` file). However, my light and candle command lines are huge, and I would risk making my project hard to maintain if I would hard-code them.

So, in conclusion, I need to know if there is a way to write a command line that would behave the same as Votive does when creating its build command line (getting all the files in project, linking them, passing project dependencies...), only in post build.

P.S.: I also had an idea of getting the whole command line from Votive, and only changing the Product file, that would also help, so if someone has suggestion on how to do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create multiple configurations of your solution / project and set a preprocessor variable to some value for one of the configurations. In your wix source, conditionally include whatever else it is that needs included based on your preprocessor variable.

Comment: Yep, that certainly is a way to do it, but we wanted to avoid creating another project.

However, what I did just now, was to change `Product.wixobj` and rerun only the linking part, which was a bit less painful to edit.
Now, I have hacked project that can produce 2 `.msi` files at price of harder maintenance.
I will see how much harder it is to change something and decide if it's better to keep things this way.